# Specifying TTL value for ping command on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I learnt from [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) that to specify TTL value we use-

```
COMMAND

$ ping www.google.com -t 100

OUTPUT

PING www.google.com (172.217.167.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=7.61 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=6.98 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=6.70 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=7.37 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=7.39 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=13.3 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=7 ttl=128 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.167.196): icmp_seq=8 ttl=128 time=7.56 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7016ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.701/9.077/15.684/3.203 ms
```

Here clearly the value of TTL=128 is greater than 100, then why did I not get a message saying that the has packet expired? I tried it for even smaller values like 2 and 3 but the command seems to have no effect.

From my understanding 128 is the number of hops that were required for the trip to google server and back, in that case if I set the limit as 100, then the packet should expire. Even with smaller values like 2 and 3, I don't get a message saying that it expired.

If my understanding is wrong, what should I do to get varying outputs when I change the TTL values?

Comment: what's displayed is the ttl of the response.

Comment: @stark I'm not sure what you mean, the output I provided is all I got

Answer (score 1):

my os is centOS 7.9
this is my test:

```
[root@test1 ~]# ping www.stackoverflow.com -c 4
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=83.0 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=82.4 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=83.0 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.69 (151.101.65.69): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=81.7 ms

--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 81.791/82.593/83.068/0.595 ms
[root@test1 ~]# ping www.stackoverflow.com -c 4 -t 4
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.65.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 100.110.4.46 (100.110.4.46) icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
From 100.110.4.46 (100.110.4.46) icmp_seq=2 Time to live exceeded
From 100.110.4.46 (100.110.4.46) icmp_seq=3 Time to live exceeded
From 100.110.4.46 (100.110.4.46) icmp_seq=4 Time to live exceeded

--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3005ms
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I am not getting this on my Linux VERSION=20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) Virtual Machine. Can anyone help me know why the -t command is not working for me?

Comment: Using -m for specifying TTL on macOS solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

1.the TTL is not a time unit, is a hop unit.

2.the ping prints the TTL value from the packet it receives.

as the man page describe:

TTL DETAILS
The TTL value of an IP packet represents the maximum number of IP routers that the packet can go through before being thrown away.  In current practice you can expect each router  in  the Internet to decrement the TTL field by exactly one.

```
       The TCP/IP specification states that the TTL field for TCP packets should be set to 60, but many systems use smaller values (4.3 BSD uses 30, 4.2 used 15).

       The  maximum  possible value of this field is 255, and most Unix systems set the TTL field of ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to 255.  This is why you will find you can ``ping'' some hosts, but not reach them with telnet(1) or ftp(1).

       In normal operation ping prints the TTL value from the packet it receives.  When a remote system receives a ping packet, it can do one of three things with the TTL field in its response:

       · Not change it; this is what Berkeley Unix systems did before the 4.3BSD Tahoe release. In this case the TTL value in the received packet will be 255 minus the number of routers  in  the round-trip path.

       · Set it to 255; this is what current Berkeley Unix systems do.  In this case the TTL value in the received packet will be 255 minus the number of routers in the path from the remote system to the pinging host.

       · Set it to some other value. Some machines use the same value for ICMP packets that they use for TCP packets, for example either 30 or 60.  Others may use completely wild values.
```

Comment: I agree, it is a hop unit, but why do I not get a packet expiration message when I set the hop limit to as small as 1.

Comment: @Exulansis Either the other end is not responding with a TTL exceeded message or something is blocking inbound ICMP (common in paranoid firewalls).